# Echo gives different output from only html

Tags: php, echo

I have this code:

```
 echo " <div class=\"col-md-4 col-lg-3\"> "
                   . get_sidebar() ."
                </div> ";
```

when I use it, sidebar doesnt show like col-md-4, it is full width.I want to use it as a sidebar.

but when I use the below html code instead of php function, page seems like how I want:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div>
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Does it work if you do `echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-lg-3'> " . get_sidebar() ."</div>";`

Comment: What gets rendered? View the source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, that the function `get_sidebar()` is making echo by itself. It is not returning HTML code, which you could join with your HTML code.

This should work:

```
echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">';
get_sidebar();
echo '</div>';
```